# GWT Unit Testing with RequestFactory / Activities

Tags: unit-testing, gwt, junit, mockito, requestfactory

I'm trying to test the start method of an Activity that uses RequestFactory.

I manage to test RF calls invoking directly the service using [this article example](http://cleancodematters.com/2011/06/18/tutorial-gwt-request-factory-%E2%80%93-part-ii/), but I'm missing something mocking RF calls called from the tested activity.

It's more clear with the code.

**EDIT** : more specific

What I really want to know, is how to replace the response of a Receiver method (onSuccess,onFailure...) called in an Activity? This way I would be able to test the code inside the receiver method.

So basically here is my activity :

```
public class MyActivity extends AbstractActivity implements MyView.Presenter {
    private List<MyEntityProxy> entities;
    private MyView view;
    private ClientFactory cf;
    private EntityRequest entityRequest;
    private AppRequestFactory rf;

    @Inject
    public ClientsListActivity(ClientsListViewEditor view, ClientFactory clientFactory) {
        this.view = view;
        this.clientFactory = clientFactory;
        rf = clientFactory.getRequestFactory();
    }

    @Override
    public void start(final AcceptsOneWidget panel, EventBus eventBus) {
        view.setPresenter(this);
        refreshEntities();
    }

    public void refreshEntities(){
         entityRequest = rf.entityRequest();
         entityRequest.getAll().with("opt1,"opt2").fire(new Receiver<List<MyEntityProxy>>() {
             @Override
            public void onSuccess(List<MyEntityProxy> response) {
                entities = response;
                entityRequest = requestFactory.clientRequest();
             }
         });
    }
    public List<MyEntityProxy> getEntities(){
        return entities;
    }
}
```

To test it in JUnit I use GwtMockito, so here is the test class MyActivityTest :

```
@RunWith(GwtMockitoTestRunner.class)
public class ClientListActivityTest{

    private MyActivity activity;
    private EventBus eventBus;
    private AppRequestFactory rf;
    @GwtMock
    private ClientFactory cf;
    @GwtMock
    private MyView;
    @GwtMock
    private AcceptsOneWidget panel;

    @Before
    public void setUp(){
        eventBus = new SimpleEventBus();
        rf = RequestFactoryHelper.create(AppRequestFactory.class);
        cf = new ClientFactory(eventBus,rf);
        activity = new MyActivity(view,cf);

    }

    @Test
    public void testStartActivity(){
        List<EntityProxy> result = new ArrayList<EntityProxy>();
        EntityProxy expectedClient = mock(EntityProxy.class);
        expectedEntity.setNom("Client 1");
        EntityProxy expectedClient2 = mock(EntityProxy.class);
        expectedEntity.setNom("Client 2");
        result.add(expectedEntity);
        result.add(expectedEntity2);
        //Here I have to change the requestFactory Call, so I try that but without success :
        Request<?> req = mock(Request.class);
        doReturn(req).when(mock(MyEntityRequest.class)).getAll();

        doAnswer(RequestFactoryHelper.ok(result)).when(req).fire(any(Receiver.class));
        activity.start(panel, eventBus);
        assertEquals(activity.getEntities().size(),2); //This Test fails size = 0
    }


}
```

My RequestFactoryHelper (inspired from [here](http://cleancodematters.com/2011/06/18/tutorial-gwt-request-factory-%E2%80%93-part-ii/) ) :

```
public class RequestFactoryHelper {

    private static class MockServiceLocator implements ServiceLocator {
        private final Map<Class<?>, Object> services = new HashMap<Class<?>, Object>();

        @Override
        public Object getInstance( Class<?> clazz ) {
            // Make sure to return always the same mocked instance for each requested type
            Object result = services.get( clazz );
            if (result == null) {
                result = mock( clazz );
                services.put( clazz, result );
            }
            return result;
        }
    }

    private static class MockServiceDecorator extends ServiceLayerDecorator {
        @Override
        public <T extends ServiceLocator> T createServiceLocator( Class<T> clazz ) {
            return (T) serviceLocator;
        }
    }

    private static MockServiceLocator serviceLocator = new MockServiceLocator();
    private static ServiceLayer serviceLayer = ServiceLayer.create( new MockServiceDecorator() );

    /**
     * Creates a {@link RequestFactory}.
     */
    public static <T extends RequestFactory> T create( Class<T> requestFactoryClass ) {
        SimpleRequestProcessor processor = new SimpleRequestProcessor( serviceLayer );
        T factory = RequestFactorySource.create( requestFactoryClass );
        factory.initialize( new SimpleEventBus(), new InProcessRequestTransport( processor ) );
        return factory;
    }

    /**
     * Returns the same service instance as used by the RequestFactory internals.
     */
    public static <T> T getService( Class<T> serviceClass ) {
        T result = (T) serviceLocator.getInstance( serviceClass );
        reset( result ); // reset mock to avoid side effects when used in multiple tests
        return result;
    }

   /**
    * Returns the value passed to {@link Receiver#onSuccess(Object)}
    */
    public static <T> T captureResult( Receiver<T> receiver ) {
        ArgumentCaptor<Object> captor = ArgumentCaptor.forClass( Object.class );
        verify( receiver ).onSuccess( (T) captor.capture() );
        return (T) captor.getValue();
    }

    public static <T> Answer<T> ok(final T result) {
         return new Answer<T>() {

            @Override
            public T answer(InvocationOnMock invocation) throws Throwable {
               Object[] args = invocation.getArguments();
               Object _receiver = args[args.length - 1];
               Receiver<T> receiver = (Receiver<T>)_receiver;
               receiver.onSuccess(result);
               return null;
            }

        };
    }
}
```

Comment: Can you be more specific on the problem you are having?

Comment: I will edit my question to specify. In my test I want to test the refresh() method, that used to get entities from the server trough RF call. So I need to replace the response in the onSuccess() method of the Receiver. After that I will be able to test the code inside the onSuccess Method depending on my response replacement in the test. Is it more clear? :s

Comment: BTW, great question. I have gone down the same route as you trying to mock requestfactory methods with no avail. If I understand your problem it is with the ok method returning the mocked result. I came up with another solution that worked very well in my case. I either use AsyncDataProvider classes or a Command pattern where I can easily mock the response from the command. This can also give you an easy hook for caching. I know this doesn't solve your problem but it is a nice work around with some added benefits. There is a video from Ray Ryan that explains how google was using Command patter

Comment: for best practices.  https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=PDuhR18-EdM

Comment: The ok method works if I create the Receiver in the test method :`Receiver<List<MyEntityProxy>> rec = mock(Receiver.class);`then I call `doAnswer(RequestFactoryHelper.ok(result)).when(req).fire(any(Receiver.class));`and I can catch the result using `List<MyEntityProxy> result = RequestFactoryHelper.captureResult(receiver);`  But doing that I'm not testing the code inside my activity.

Answer (score 1):

This is how I tested the Receiver method "onSuccess". I created a custom Answer for Mockito.doAnswer.

The code to test.

```
public void myMethod(String arg1, String arg2) {
    requestFactory.adminRequest().someMethod(arg1, arg2).fire(new Receiver<Void>() {
        @Override
        public void onSuccess(Void response) {
            placeController.goTo(new MyPlace());
        }
    });
}
```

The test.

```
@Test
public void testMyMethod() {
    String arg1 = "arg1";
    String arg2 = "arg2";
    when(requestFactory.adminRequest()).thenReturn(adminRequest);
    when(adminRequest.someMethod(arg1, arg2)).thenReturn(request);
    doAnswer(new Answer<Void>() {

        @Override
        public Void answer(InvocationOnMock invocation) throws Throwable {
            Object[] args = invocation.getArguments();
            Receiver<Void> receiver = (Receiver<Void>) args[0];
            receiver.onSuccess(null);
            return null;
        }
    }).when(request).fire(any(Receiver.class));

    myActivity.myMethod(arg1, arg2);
    verify(adminRequest).someMethod(arg1, arg2);
    verify(request).fire(any(Receiver.class));
    verify(placeController).goTo(any(myPlace.class));

}
```

requestFactory, adminRequest, request and placeController are all mocks.